# MVC form block email domain

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a registration form on our site and in this is an email TextBoxFor and it works great until I got tasked with changing it to block users from using a specific email domain.

So how can i get the form to block the user from using say "name@domainX.com" where DomainX.com is the bad domain but anything else passes and the account is registered.

I have looked at using jQuery and got a popup box but that is not as neat as just forcing a error in the validation summary.  Looking at the data annotations on the Model Class and there is nothing there other than a RegEx I can think of.

Suggestions please.

Cliff.

Answer (score 0):

You are right regex along with data annotation is the way to go. Try this `(?!^([A-Z|a-z|0-9](\.|_){0,1})+[A-Z|a-z|0-9]\@(domainX)+\.(com))`

Comment: This would work if I wanted just domainX.com emails to work but I want everything BUT the domainX.com addresses to pass.  Basically I need to stop people using a company email address as the firewall blocks the emails so I need to force them to use a personal address.

Comment: prepend  a negative lookahead  i.e ` ?! ` or you could add the logic in your email property to check whether or not the email matches using  `Regex.IsMatch`